# How are these C functions different?

Tags: c, pointers

I am new to C and was trying to understand the pointer concepts of C. Can anyone help me that how are these functions are different?

```
#include<stdio.h>

func1(int *p){
    printf("%d",*p);
}

func2(int *p){
    printf("%d",*p);
}

func3(int *p){
    printf("%d",*p);
}

void main(){
    int p=3;
    func1(&p);
    func2(*p);
    func3(p); 
}
```

Comment: They aren't, nor in terms of functionality, neither in terms of readlility.

Comment: The functions appear to be identical. Did you type them wrong?

Comment: (Cough) The *functions* are all the same... But surely your compiler warns about passing on a wrong argument?

Comment: This code shouldn't compile.

Comment: The code itself contains error. Please re-look and edit the question.

Comment: `printf("%d",*p)` should be `printf("%p",*p)`. `func2(*p);` should cause a segfault. The entire program should spew warnings during compile.

Comment: @Matt - You're right... I thought he was printing the pointer. Not sure how I missed the dereference. My bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 3 functions are the same. The difference is the argument you pass to them.

**&p**: get the reference (memory adress) of the variable p.

***p**: assumes that p is a memory address and get the value that is stored in that position. In this case, you will get a sigsev because you are trying to access to position 3 of memory system.

**p**: get p, in that case 3.

The functions receive a pointer, and prints the value storage in that position as an integer.

Answer (score 0):

The three functions are expecting a pointer to an `int`. In the first call only do you supply such a pointer.

`&p` is a pointer to an `int`.

`*p` is an (illegal) dereference to an `int`.

`p` is a plain `int`.